# How do I create a filter for time (hhmm) intervals on data studio

Tags: looker-studio

I just started using Data Studio and am using a data source from Big Query. I have a filter for date (allowing me to adjust all the graphs according to that date) but I want to create another filter that allows me to create 2 drop down (1. Start time 2. End time) with a between in the middle. I have been able to create a time interval using two filters where the user must manually input the date (again) followed by the hhmm (“YYYYMMDDhhmm” format) and the goal is to minimize the amount that the user must manually input, therefore, creating one filter with two drop down menus that has an in between statement. Is this even possible on Data studio or is there anything else I can do similar to what I’m looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Data Studio can recognize datatime format like this 'YYYYMMDD' as default.
So you should change it in data studio option. You can do it via create new field with regular expression.
And you can use DateFiler control that have advanced option ( you can find it in setting)

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, I don’t think this would help me create time intervals for a given day using only one filter. For ex: start time (drop down) *inserts 4pm* between end time (drop down) *inserts 5pm*

Comment: Oh yes. You wanted to time instead date. You can do it by makeing community connector by appscript